# Proving $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\{\frac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}\right\}\le \frac{9}{14}n^2$？

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, inequalities

For any postive integer $n$ and for any postive real numbers $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$, show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\{\dfrac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}\right\}\le \dfrac{9}{14}n^2$$
Let
\begin{align}
x_{i}&=1+i\varepsilon, &
i&=1,2,\cdots,\tfrac{2}{7}n \,,\\
x_{j}&=2-\left(j+\tfrac{2}{7}n\right)\varepsilon, &
j&=\tfrac{2}{7}n+1,\cdots,\tfrac{5}{7}n \,,\\
x_{k}&=4-\left(k+\tfrac{10}{7}n\right)\varepsilon,&
k&=\tfrac{5}{7}n+1,\cdots,n \,,
\end{align}
then
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\left\{\frac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}\right\}\to\frac{9}{14}n^2,\quad\varepsilon\to 0^+,\;n\to+\infty.$$
This inequality  discovered by a Chinese student, and maybe  this coefficient $\dfrac{9}{14}$ is the best.

Maybe
$$ \left(\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 =\frac{1}{12}+\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2\pi m x)}{\pi^2 m^2}$$

**ADD it: conjecture:**
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\{\dfrac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}\right\}\le \dfrac{9}{14}n^2-\dfrac{1}{7}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\cos{(a(x_{i}-t))}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin{(a(x_{i}-t))}\right)^2\right)dt?$$
where $a=\arccos{(-\frac{3}{4})}$

But it still failed. The problem seems to be related to the series form of Bernoulli polynomials? Would love to see any better ideas. Thank you all.

Comment: "This inequality discovered by a Chinese student" -- Discovered in what sense? Is there a proof? Do you a reference to it? It is actually unclear what the question here is.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear that the question is "Is it true that $\sum \left\{ \tfrac{x_i}{x_j} \right\} \leq \tfrac{9}{14} n^2$ for all positive real numbers $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$?" Also with an implied question: "What is the smallest constant which can replace $9/14$ here?"

Comment: Perhaps $\{x\}+\{1/x\}<3/2$ provides a good bound. I think it gives $\frac{3}{2}\binom{n}{2}+n$, or $\frac34$ instead of$\frac{9}{14}$.

Comment: @TheBestMagician: This gives the bound $(3/4)n^2 +O(n)$, which however is worse than $9/14<3/4$.

Comment: If you put $c_m = \text{sup} \tfrac{1}{m(m-1)} \sum_{i,j=1}^m \left\{ \tfrac{x_i}{x_j} \right\}$, then we have $c_2 \geq c_3 \geq c_4 \geq \cdots$. The sup is over $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^m$. (Proof: Just take the sum $\sum_{i,j=1}^n \left\{ \tfrac{x_i}{x_j} \right\}$ and write it as a linear combination of the $\binom{n}{m}$ sums over $m$-element subsets of $\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \}$.) So @TheBestMagician's observation is that $c_2 = 3/4$, and it seems like it would be worth computing the next few values of $c_m$.

Comment: On the other hand, put $d_m = \text{sup} \tfrac{1}{m^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^m \left\{ \tfrac{x_i}{x_j} \right\}$. Then $d_n = c_n + O(1/n)$, so both sequences approach the same limit (and the $c$'s do approach a limit, since they are decreasing). We have $d_m \leq d_{km}$ (proof: take $k$ copies of each number). So each $d$ gives a lower bound for the limit, and each $c$ gives an upper bound. We should be able to get some pretty tight bounds this way.

Comment: Just to make sure: what is exactly $\{y\}$ ? Is it $y-\lfloor y\rfloor$, or is it the distance to the integers ?

Comment: For the lower bound, if we take $n/2$ numbers slightly bigger than $1$ and $n/2$ numbers slightly less than $2$ then we can have a constant arbitrarily close to $\frac{5}{8}$ (which is very slightly less than $\frac{9}{14}$).

Comment: is not it true that $\sum_{i,j} (\{x_i/x_j\}-9/14)u_iu_j\leqslant 0$ for all real $u_i$, that is, that the kernel $\{x/y\}-9/14$ is non-positive definite?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Interesting idea, but, probably, not for large $n$. On the other hand, it is easy to reduce the problem to the consideration of a finite number of cases. Alas, my reduction needs to be refined quite a bit to make this observation useful with modern computers...

Comment: @FedorPetrov OK, reduced it to 1024 cases and checked them by brute force. The key idea is to prove the stronger inequality with $\{z\}+\{1/z\}$ replaced by $1+1/z$ for $z\ge 2$. The rest tomorrow: it is past midnight here now :-)

Comment: @math110 I cannot verify your example from the edit 9h ago, please check. In this case I get $\frac{111}{196} < \frac {5}{8} < \frac {9}{14}$ for the limit. I also checked the other sign combinations ($ 1 \pm \ldots, 2 \pm \ldots, 4 \pm \ldots$).

Comment: I used Mathematica, something like: Apart@FindSequenceFunction[Rationalize@N[Table[{n, n^-2 Total[FractionalPart[Outer[Divide, Array[x[##] &, n], Array[x[##] &, n]]], 2] /.x[i_] ->Piecewise[{{1 + i ee, 
            0 < i <= (2 n)/7}, {2 + (i - (2 n)/7) ee, (2 n)/
             7 < i <= (5 n)/7}, {4 + (i - (5 n)/7) ee, (5 n)/
             7 < i <= n}}]}, {n, 14, 100, 14}] /. ee ->      10^-30], n]

Comment: I found the problem with the OP's example. Changing the definition of $x_i$ to, e.g., $x_i=\begin{cases} 
1+i \epsilon & 0<i\leq2n/7\\
2-(i+ 2n/7) \epsilon & 2n/7<i\leq5n/7\\
4-(i+10n/7) \epsilon & 5n/7<i\leq n\\
\end{cases}$ gives the correct limit $9/14$.

Comment: Similar problems  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h3122562p28384307   https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h3054889p27528763

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal,Thank you， It’s true that I wrote down the waiting list wrong at first.Ihave edit it

Comment: @math110 It was me who corrected your example. You now have added another question in form of the conjecture, this is not so good. You should consider to accept the best answer to your original question (which might be the one by @fedja). Either move your conjecture question to a comment or ask a new question.

Comment: Moreover, since the LHS is invariant under the multiplication of all $x_j$ by the same constant and the RHS of your new inequality is obviously not, this new conjecture looks slightly outlandish as written and can easily be refuted by sending all $x_j$ to $0$ while preserving the ratios. I'm less demanding than @FredHucht in terms of etiquette but if you edit new questions into your posts, make sure that they make some sense at least. Also the word "conjecture" means something you have an extensive evidence for, just cannot prove, not some random thing that crossed your mind.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

OK, here is a fairly simple proof that for any positive integer $n$ and any positive real numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$,
$$ \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\left\{\frac{x_i}{x_j}\right\}\leq \frac{9}{14}n^2\,.$$
That the constant $\frac{9}{14}$ cannot be improved has already been shown by the OP. I wonder if the Chinese student who invented the problem had the same one in mind.

Consider the function
$$
f(z)=\begin{cases}
1+z,&0\le z\le 1/2
\\
z+\frac 1z-1, &\frac 12\le z\le 2
\\
1+\frac 1z, &z\ge 2
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $f(z)=f(1/z)$ and $f(z)\ge\{z\}+\{1/z\}$ for all $z>0$. We shall show that
$$
\sum_{i,j}f(x_i/x_j)u_i u_j\le \frac 97\|u\|_{\ell^1}^2
$$
for all non-negative sequences $u$ with finite support and for all $x_j>0$.

Note that $f$ is a nice continuous function that is increasing near $0$, decreasing near $+\infty$ and *convex* except for two singular points $\frac 12$ and $2$. The last property allows one to choose any subset of $x_j$, replace them by $tx_j$ and move $t$ up or down to increase (or, at least, keep constant) the LHS until some ratio between the moving $x_j$ and the stationary ones becomes $2$ or $\frac 12$. Doing that a few times, we'll arrive to the situation when the graph in which $i$ is joined with $j$ if and only if $x_i/x_j\in\{\frac 12,2\}$ is connected (otherwise just move a connected component until acquiring a new edge). In normal English that means that all $x_j$ are just powers of $2$ (times some irrelevant positive common factor).

Thus, subtracting $1$ from each entry, we see that our matrix entries are just $2^{-|i-j|}$ for $i\ne j$ and $0$ for $i=j$. where $1\le i,j\le m$ (we unite the $u_j$ for colliding $x_j$, of course). Let's call that matrix $A(m)$. We want to show that
$$
\langle A(m)u,u\rangle=\sum_{i,j}A(m)_{ij}u_iu_j\le\frac 27\|u\|_{\ell^1}^2
$$
now.

It is time to move $u_i$. Notice first of all that we do not need zeroes in the middle: we can just move the support chunks together increasing the coefficient at each product $u_iu_j$ discarding the zero tail afterwards and reducing $m$. Next, assuming that we have full support, take some vector $v$ with sum $0$ and replace $u$ by $u+tv$. The RHS will not change until we kill one entry. The LHS will become
$$
\langle A(m)u,u\rangle+2t\langle A(m)u,v\rangle+t^2\langle A(m)v,v\rangle
$$
so, we cannot improve it and kill an entry only if $A(m)$ is negative definite on the zero sum subspace of $\mathbb R^m$. The last property fails for $m\ge 4$: just take $v=(2,1,-1,-2,0,0,\dots)$ to get $\langle A(m)v,v\rangle=0$. Thus we are interested in $m=2,3$ only. According to the last displayed formula, to find the optimal $u$, we need just to solve $A(m)u=e$ where $e$ is the vector of all $1$'s (the trivial instance of the Lagrange multiplier idea). For $m=2$, we get $u=(2,2)$ with the constant $\frac 14$ (Alexei's example). For $m=3$, we get $u=(1,\frac 32,1)$ and the ratio $\frac 27$ (the Chinese student example).

That's it.

Comment: you're very smart.

Comment: Can you please add something to the beginning saying exactly what you are proving here? It's hard to read this without understanding the punchline ahead of time.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Not really. I just picked up some tricks over the years and some of them work occasionally. You can easily do the same: just put everything you meet in your mouth and try to chew and swallow it. In mathematics, in the worst case scenario you'll get a slight indigestion and in the best case you'll grow wings or gills :lol:

Comment: @SamHopkins Erm... Haven't I done *exactly that* right after the definition of $f$? What was unclear?

Comment: What confused me is that there were multiple different constants mentioned in the various answers and comments. But I think you are showing $\frac{9}{14}$ is the true best constant, right? I edited the first sentence of your post to make this claim; apologies if that was not what you intended.

Comment: @SamHopkins (Minor note:) I think tightness was shown in the OP. Fedja is proving the validity of $\frac{9}{14}$ as an upper bound.

Comment: @SamHopkins OK. I just edited your note a bit in the spirit of mathworker21's remark (which was absolutely correct).

Comment: @fedja: This (your response to TheSimpliFire) is a nice attempt, but you must have noticed yourself, as everyone else has, I'm sure, that there is a certain type of (analysis) question, of which this one is a good example, that remains unanswered until you or Terry come along.

Comment: So something is implausible about the claim "anyone can do it"...

Comment: @ChristianRemling It is plausible, trust me. If you want to refute my claim, show me somebody who followed my (or Terry's) advice about how to approach math for 10 years or so and hasn't succeeded. About most people I certainly can only repeat Chesterton's famous quote "The Christian ideal has not been tried and found wanting. It has been found difficult and left untried.". And yeah, it does require certain effort to become Terry Tao. With me it is much easier: just be omnivorous and forget the ideas that some problems are not worth trying and that one's time is too valuable to play games.

Comment: @fedja Fantastic advice. However, and I hope I am not overstepping my boundaries, but it seems true to me that the strongest mathematicians (or people in any field actually) are people with both profound work ethic and talent. I think you know what I am implying…

Comment: @NateRiver  "I think you know what I am implying…" To be honest, you can imply many things, so I would appreciate a clarification :-). Talent determines only your maximal speed of progress (and that one does vary a lot, no question about that). How far one can go is determined entirely by their perseverance and general attitudes. Most people just shoot themselves in the foot in the process in various ways and then get surprised that they cannot walk as far as some others in the end.

Answer (score 21):

Too long for a comment.

For $c>0$, the following two claims are equivalent.

**Claim 1.** An inequality $$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\{\dfrac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}\right\}\leqslant cn^2$$
holds for all positive numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

**Claim 2.** An inequality $$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\{\dfrac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}\right\}u_iu_j\leqslant cn\sum u_i^2$$
holds for all positive numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and all real $u_1,\ldots,u_n$.

Clearly, Claim 2 yields Claim 1 by taking $u_i=1$ for all $i$. Now assume that Claim 1 holds for all $n$. Proving Claim 2, we may suppose that $u_i$ are non-negative (otherwise replace $u_i$ to $|u_i|$, LHS can only increase and RHS does not change), and also rational (by continuity) and finally integer (by homogenuity). Then apply Claim 1 to a multiset containing $u_i$ elements equal to $x_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. We get $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\{\dfrac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}\right\}u_iu_j\leqslant c\left(\sum u_i\right)^2\leqslant cn\sum u_i^2,$$
that is, Claim 2 holds.

Now in order to use Bochner's positive definite kernel theorem we denote $x_i=e^{t_i}$, then Claim 2 deals with a symmetric matrix $f(t_i-t_j)$ for $f(t):=(\{e^t\}+\{e^{-t}\})/2$. If $f(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{it\xi}d\mu(\xi)$ for a real signed measure $\mu=\mu_+-\mu_-$, then
$$
\sum_{j,k} f(t_j-t_k)u_ju_k=\int \left|\sum_{j=1}^n u_je^{it_j\xi}\right|^2d\mu(\xi)\leqslant cn\sum_{j=1}^n u_j^2
$$
for $c=\mu_+(\mathbb{R})$.

Thus, if $\mu_+(\mathbb{R})\leqslant 9/14$, the inequality holds.

Comment: you're smart. ${}{}$

Comment: So, we are to take the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of your function $f$, and then compute $\int \max(\hat{f}, 0)$?

Comment: Ignoring convergence, $\int (\{e^t\}+\{e^{-t}\})/2 e^{iwt} dt = \int \{e^t \} \cos (wt) dt$, which is $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^t \cos(wt) dt + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\log n}^{\log (n+1)} (e^t-n) \cos(wt) dt$.

Comment: If we stop the sum at $n=N-1$ instead of $n=\infty$, this is $\tfrac{1}{w} \sum_{n=2}^{N-1} \sin(w \log n) + \tfrac{N-1+w^2}{w(1+w^2)} \sin(w \log N) + \tfrac{N}{1+w^2}  \cos (w \log N)$. (Thanks Mathematica!) To a naive combinatorialist like me, this doesn't look convergent. But I'm sure analysts have their ways to keep going :)

Comment: maybe we can find $f(x,t)$ such $$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\{\frac{x_{i}}{x_{j}}\}\le\dfrac{9}{14}n^2-\int_{0}^{1}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i},t))^2dt?$$

Comment: @DavidESpeyer something like that. The inverse Fourier transform is not a function, though. Fedja suggests at first use a bound $\{e^t\}+\{e^{-t}\}\leqslant 1+\min(2\cosh t-1, e^{-|t|})$, for this majorant the inverse Fourier transform is delta-function plus some explicit genuine function.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I'm afraid that even for the majorant (for which the inequality still holds) $\mu_+$ and $\mu_-$ are mixed together too much on the line, so that discarding $\mu_-$ entirely may result in a worse bound. But, as you correctly noted, for piecewise exponential function $\mu_+$ can be computed explicitly (I was too lazy to finish the computation), so, maybe, I'm wrong :-)

Comment: @fedja Yes, it does not work, according to D. Krachun's computations, and this agrees with the fact that we have an equality case - what could it do at Fourier side?

Answer (score 5):

**Update 04.01.2024**

The answer below is incorrect, as it only takes into account sets with two groups of $x_i$. As [fedja showed in his brilliant answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461558/488821), certain sets with three groups (of relative size $2,3,2$) will give the OP's bound $9/14$.
While the OP's present example does not give this value (but $111/196$, see my comments above), the set
\begin{align}
x_i=\begin{cases}
 1+i \epsilon & 0<i\leq \frac{2n}{7}\\
 2-\big(i+ \frac{2n}{7}\big) \epsilon & \frac{2n}{7}<i\leq \frac{5n}{7}\\ 
4-\big(i+\frac{10n}{7}\big) \epsilon & \frac{5n}{7}<i\leq n\\ \end{cases}
\end{align}
leads to $S_\infty=\frac{9}{14}$ as claimed.

**Old answer**

I assume that $\{x_i\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x_i>0$.
As already suggested by [@AlekseiKulikov](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1197052) in the comments above, a maximal set of $x_j$ is
\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
x_i = \begin{cases}
1+i \epsilon & 0   < i \leq n/2 \\
2-i \epsilon & n/2 < i \leq n, 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
with $0<\epsilon\ll 1$.
Then,
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
S_n=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n \left\{ \frac{x_i}{x_j} \right\}
 = \begin{cases}
\frac 5 8 - \frac 1 {4n} & n \text{ even}\\
\frac 5 8 - \frac {n-3/8}{(2n-1)^2} & n \text{ odd,}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which goes to $S_\infty=5/8$ from below for large $n$. This is slightly smaller than $9/14$.

**Addendum 1**

For arbitrary integer accumulation values $x_+,x_-$ instead of the integers $1,2$ in \eqref{eq:1}, the limiting values $S_\infty(x_+,x_-)$ are given by:

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc}
  x_+ \, \backslash \, x_-& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\hline
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{8} & \frac{7}{12} & \frac{9}{16} & \frac{11}{20} & \frac{13}{24} & \frac{15}{28} &
   \frac{17}{32} & \frac{19}{36} & \frac{21}{40} \\
 2 & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{13}{24} & \frac{5}{8} & \frac{19}{40} & \frac{7}{12} & \frac{25}{56} &
   \frac{9}{16} & \frac{31}{72} & \frac{11}{20} \\
 3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{13}{24} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{25}{48} & \frac{17}{30} & \frac{5}{8} & \frac{37}{84} &
   \frac{49}{96} & \frac{7}{12} & \frac{49}{120} \\
 4 & \frac{5}{16} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{25}{48} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{41}{80} & \frac{13}{24} & \frac{65}{112} &
   \frac{5}{8} & \frac{61}{144} & \frac{19}{40} \\
 5 & \frac{3}{10} & \frac{19}{40} & \frac{17}{30} & \frac{41}{80} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{61}{120} & \frac{37}{70} &
   \frac{89}{160} & \frac{53}{90} & \frac{5}{8} \\
 6 & \frac{7}{24} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{13}{24} & \frac{61}{120} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{85}{168} &
   \frac{25}{48} & \frac{13}{24} & \frac{17}{30} \\
 7 & \frac{2}{7} & \frac{25}{56} & \frac{37}{84} & \frac{65}{112} & \frac{37}{70} & \frac{85}{168} & \frac{1}{2} &
   \frac{113}{224} & \frac{65}{126} & \frac{149}{280} \\
 8 & \frac{9}{32} & \frac{5}{16} & \frac{49}{96} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{89}{160} & \frac{25}{48} & \frac{113}{224} &
   \frac{1}{2} & \frac{145}{288} & \frac{41}{80} \\
 9 & \frac{5}{18} & \frac{31}{72} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{61}{144} & \frac{53}{90} & \frac{13}{24} & \frac{65}{126} &
   \frac{145}{288} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{181}{360} \\
 10 & \frac{11}{40} & \frac{3}{10} & \frac{49}{120} & \frac{19}{40} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{17}{30} & \frac{149}{280} &
   \frac{41}{80} & \frac{181}{360} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}\end{align}
The maximum value $S_\infty=5/8$ is taken for $x_- = 2x_+$.

Comment: what was the point of this?

Comment: I think that this choice of $x_i$ gives the maximum possible value for the sum.

Comment: See the OP's comment or the edit the OP made.

Comment: @mathworker21 I cannot reproduce the added example, see my comments above.